# Kubernetes: Как войти в sh мертвого контейнера

Tags: docker, kubernetes

В одном из контейнеров nginx не может найти dns имя и выключается вместе с контейнером. Как заглянуть внутрь, то есть запустить тот же image в том же поде, но с процессом sh?

Comment: да как обычно: `$ docker run -it имя.образа программа`

Answer (score 1):

Вы не можете запустить тот же под тк он уже отработал и умер. Но вы можете запустить тот же образ, но с нужным вам шеллом

```
docker run --rm -it image sh
```

Это позволит вам как в песочнице поиграть с контейнером и посмотреть, что мешает запуститься приложению.